# pip install MySql-python==1.2.4 fails on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I came across few other questions on Stackoverflow about the same but none of them solved my issue and they didn't have exactly same environment details

1. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
2. Trying to install Mysql-python==1.2.4
3. pip version 1.5

Ends with: IOError: Could not build the egg.

Dump link here: http://pastebin.com/WcxpfZYe

Python 2.7

Let me know if any other details needed.

With pip version 1.4 it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this error too.

You can use `MySQL-python==1.2.5.`

The error might be fixed by [this commit](https://github.com/farcepest/MySQLdb1/commit/a050932372d7b94e8606caa0f242dd2ff4b77cfe).

Or, If you really want to use MySQL-python=1.2.4, try to install `setuptools==0.9.8` before install it.
(The version of pip is not so important. check the version of setuptools).

Answer (score 3):

I found this error too but I had to use `MySQL-python==1.2.4`.

Try to install:

1. `setuptools==0.9.8`
2. `distribute==0.6.29`
3. Finally, `MySQL==1.2.4`.

This worked for me.